# why is the inscription displayed and not the number?

Tags: python, format

I don't understand what i am doing wrong, why "s" outputs like a title

```
print('* xa=',xa,'             *              s=,{:9.f}',      '*'. format('s'))
```

[image: this is how it looks after running a programm]

I expected that i will see

```
s=(there would be number of s)
```

Comment: `'             *              s=,{:9.f}'` is not followed by `.format(variable)`, so it's not a format string, it's just a regular string to be printed.

Comment: What number did you expect to be printed after `s=`?

Comment: i did it but now i see an error about invalid syntax and forgetting comma, but there is a comma before '

Comment: Without seeing what you did I can't tell what you did wrong. But see my answer.

Comment: s is a square of firgure with random sides, so i expected a random square with one number after comma

Comment: But you expected that even though you didn't put it after `s=`.

Answer (score 0):

You put `.format` in the wrong place, it should be after `'             *              s=,{:9.f}'`. And the argument should be the variable that should be formatted, so you shouldn't put `s` in quotes.

In modern Python it's easier to put everything together into an f-string instead of using `.format()`.

```
print(f'* xa={xa}             *              s={s:9.f}      *')
```